# Insert string inside another string from one index to another index in between the string

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I have a SQL select query already written in java. Now i want to select few more columns. In that case i need to write column names before the index of from keyword.
Like this 
Initial query-

```
StringBuffer query;
query = " Select name,age,dob from employee"
```

New query should be like this-

```
query = "select name , age , dob,city from employee"
```

For this i tried `query= query.insert(indexof(dob),"city");`

But i think this will overwrite from.
My question comes down to whether insert creates enough space to insert the string or it overwrites the earlier string?
Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you want to insert query results into `stringbuffer` or query strings? Are you referring to storing some `prepared` statements?

Comment: I am trying to build a query using string buffer.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar that is a bad idea. You should really use prepared statements and a library to build them for you. Read all about SQL injection to understand why it is hard to write good code with non-prepared, non-sanitized queries.

Comment: Also note that StringBuilder is preferred to StringBuffer (it is more efficient in the common case of not having multiple threads access it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of getting index value of `dob`, get index value of `from`

```
query= query.insert(original.indexOf("from"),"city ");
```

Comment: Wont this insert city after from?

Comment: No - indexOf returns the index of the start of the string it searches for

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer("Select name,age,dob from employee");
 query.insert(query.indexOf("from"), "city ");
```